# Retrieve the most recent values on records on 3 primary keys mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have this table

```
+--------+--------+------+----------+----+----+
| pm     | pm2    | pm3  | date     |at1 | at2|
+--------+--------+------+----------+----+----+
| 111111 |        |      | 1/12/19  | a  |    |
| 111111 |  1010  |      | 1/12/19  | b  |    |
| 111111 |  1010  |      | 5/12/19  |    | e  |
| 111111 |  1010  |  56  | 1/12/19  |a   | d  |
| 111111 |  1010  |  56  | 5/12/19  |    | c  |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

and my desired output is the following:

```
+--------+--------+------+----------+----+----+
| pm     | pm2    | pm3  | date     |at1 | at2|
+--------+--------+------+----------+----+----+
| 111111 |        |      | 1/12/19  | a  |    |
| 111111 |  1010  |      | 5/12/19  | b  | e  |
| 111111 |  1010  |  56  | 5/12/19  | a  | c  |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

What I want to do is check the combination of the three pms, and then update each of the fields with the most recent value (if there is any - if not then it just keeps the value it already has)
I am using this code

```sql
select * from tab  INNER JOIN(select pm1, pm2, pm3, MAX(date) as maxdt 
    from tab 
    group by pm1, pm2, pm3)ms 
    on (tab.pm1 = ms.pm1 and tab.pm2 = ms.pm2 and tab.pm3 = ms.pm3 and date = maxdt)
```

but it is not entirely working and I am not so familiar with sql. Someone that could help me? Thank you!

Comment: These keys are not 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are nulls in the columns `pm2` and `pm3`, so instead of `=` in the `ON` clause you should use [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) (NULL-safe equal to operator) and in the select list use [`coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
select t.pm, t.pm2, t.pm3, t.date,
  coalesce(t.at1, g.at1) at1, coalesce(t.at2, g.at2) at2
from tab t inner join (
  select pm, pm2, pm3,
    max(date) date, max(at1) at1, max(at2) at2
  from tab  
  group by pm, pm2, pm3  
) g on g.pm = t.pm and g.pm2 <=> t.pm2 and g.pm3 <=> t.pm3 and g.date = t.date
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jMxvHp4LsuG9LmFxV98MZ4/0).
Results:

```
| pm     | pm2  | pm3 | date                | at1 | at2 |
| ------ | ---- | --- | ------------------- | --- | --- |
| 111111 |      |     | 0001-12-19 00:00:00 | a   |     |
| 111111 | 1010 |     | 0005-12-19 00:00:00 | b   | e   |
| 111111 | 1010 | 56  | 0005-12-19 00:00:00 | a   | c   |
```

Comment: So if I would like to not see the rows where `pm2=pm3=null` and update every row based on pm, I should make `group by pm2, pm3 on g.pm = t.pm and g.date = t.date`, right?

Comment: If you don't want the rows with nulls, replace the null safe operator `<=>` with `=`.

Comment: I want the rows with null. What I was wondering is this: I have a row with `pm=111, pm2=pm3=Null, at1=b, date=21/10/19` and a row `pm=111, pm2=11, pm3=Null, at1=c, date=20/10/2019`. How can I alter the query so its outcome would be `pm=111, pm2=11, date=21/10/2019, at1=b` (and don't show the row where `pm2=pm3=Null` but update the fields on every row that has the same `pm`?

Comment: This is a different requirement, you can't do it with this query.

Comment: Then I should create a new question. Thank you @forpas!